# Debugging chrome "remotely"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

If I start google chrome from the command line:

1. How can I start chrome in "debug" mode so that it stops at the first `debugger;` statement or breakpoint?
2. I heard one was impossible - that you are supposed to connect to the chrome process from another process and debug it that way. How can we do that? Is there some JavaScript hook that we can listen to that will notify that the process has been connected to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I start chrome in "debug" mode so that it stops at the first debugger; statement or breakpoint?

e.g. with puppeteer

- Launch with devtools open : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions and chrome will automatically stop at any `debugger;` statements

[image]

Comment: thanks I am going to try this. Chrome has a flag call `--auto-open-devtools-for-`, but that wasn't working with the `GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher` tool...so I will try `puppeteer` instead...

Comment: * `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`